# From the Right Click menu it is not clicking on a specific option Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

In an project, I want to right click on an option and from there I want to choose "Open Link in New Window". I have written the following selenium-java code. In this code it is crawling on the "Open Link in New Window" but after that it is not clicking that option to open my required link in a new window. If you want you can directly copy and paste my code to visualize the execute flow. Please help me to understand where is the mistake I have done....My intention is to open a link in new window

```
package pack_001;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;

public class mail {
    public static WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            WebElement env=driver.findElement(By.linkText("Java - Environment Setup"));
            System.out.println("Env point out");
            Actions oAction = new Actions(driver);

            oAction.moveToElement(env);
            oAction.contextClick(env).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).click().build().perform();  /* this should click on the option*/



    }

}
```

Comment: To get the same effect, you can create a new `WebDriver` and navigate to that link. Eg: `driver2.get(env.getAttribute("href"));`

Comment: If you don't mind can you please elaborate this part. I mean if I have identified a link WebElement, called 'element', how exactly I can open it on a new window....

Comment: To create a new window you need to create a new `WebDrive`, eg: `WebDriver driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();`, and to open the `element` link in this new window, you can do this `drive2.get(element.getAttribute("href"));`. This will work if `element` is a HTML `<a>` element. Also, Firefox has a shortcut to open a link in a new window `SHIFT + Left Click`.

Comment: Thanks ....for your explanation

Comment: Hey Man, You saved me.. I modified your solution according to my need and Env. and it helped me out of the problem. Thanks man, once again.

Answer (score 0):

HI instead of click use ENTER it will work

```
oAction.moveToElement(env);
oAction.contextClick(env).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

also why click will not work cause click clicks in middle of the given webElement and new Tab option is not a webElement

This will surely open the tab in new windwo

**UPDATE**

```
public class DropDownSelection {
    public static WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

       // i have used a sample url exactly as similar to your problem
       driver.get("http://desirulez.biz/category/wrestlingnetwork/wwe/wwe-raw/");
       driver.manage().window().maximize();

       // way One
       Actions oAction = new Actions(driver);

       // now simply hover over the WWE - Menu in your case
       WebElement Menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='menu-item-8']/a"));
       oAction.moveToElement(Menu).build().perform();
       // hovering will open its sub-menu - Configure in your case
       // now identify the sub-menu that you want to click/hover
       WebElement Configure = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='menu-item-8']/ul/li[7]/a"));
       oAction.moveToElement(Configure).build().perform();
       // now hovering over it will open its sub menu
       // in your case Manage
       // now identify the sub-menu that you want to click/hover
       WebElement Manage = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='menu-item-8']/ul/li[7]/ul/li/a"));
       oAction.moveToElement(Manage).click().build().perform();

       // way Two
       // note if you want to chain above you can even do that like below
       oAction.moveToElement(Menu).moveToElement(Configure).moveToElement(Manage).click().build().perform();
}
}
```

Hope this solves your query

Comment: Let me explain you little bit more about my goal. Your solution is nicely working in most of the websites and I also found that this is a convenient way. But the environment where I was actually trying to open a link in a new window there is not stable. Sometimes it is working and sometimes it is failing. The flow is something like this- It would click the "menu" option->dro down list->Choose "Configure" option->another submenu-> Now I need to open "Manage" in a new window. So There Upto "Manage" option there is no problem. But the above solution is clicking on "Manage" sometimes successfully

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong you are trying to open a Manage Menu which is sub menu of configure and configure is the sub menu of Menu right if yes then in that case why are you using context click ,it can be directly achieved without that ,also above solution was for right click mouse handling

Comment: plz confirm so that i can help you with a working code for your problem

Comment: Whatever you understood that is absolutely correct. Your code is also fine. But I was my mistake that I could not explain my proper intention of opening it by contextClick(). Actually for which Env. I am writing the code that should be compatible with both Firefox and Chrome. Now whenever we are simply clicking the "Manage" option in Firefox it is opening a new window for Manage option. So there I could directly switchTo() and continue my automation. But when the same is doing on Chrome it is opening "Manage" on a new Tab under the same window. So switchTo() is failing to identify the new tab,

Comment: ...(continuation) as switchTo() is used to change focus among the windows, not among the tabs. That was the reason, for chrome I was trying to open the " Manage" option explicitly on a new window. So that I could generate a window id to switch.